# Remove the "Close" icon on a Form while DevExpress is used

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I need to be able to remove the <kbd>Close</kbd> button on a Windows form. I know it is possible using this snippet:

```
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= ~WS_SYSMENU;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

However, I also need to apply a **DevExpress DefaultLookAndFeel** to my form. The above snippet doesn't seem to work if you have a **DevExpress DefaultLookAndFeel** enabled on my form. Is there a possible solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To hide only the XtraForm's Close button (x) please set the [XtraForm.CloseBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsXtraForm_CloseBoxtopic) property to `false`. This property is in effect when the Form Skinning feature is enabled.

Or you can set the [Form.ControlBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx) property to `false` to make the entire form's control box invisible.

Comment: It seems that this solution works with the newer version of DevExpress. I found out that our version is waaaay outdated. It's just 9.3 :(